# laravel vue, using vue code in blade template

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to access vue component function data in a laravel blade that includes the component but I can't get it to work.  Using this code, the site loads to a blank page, but if I remove the `@` from the blade span, then the page loads with the autocomplete input and it doesn't access the data

autocomplete.blade.php

```
<autocomplete :items="items" v-model="item" :get-label="getLabel" :component-item='template' @update-items="updateItems">
</autocomplete>
<div>
    <span>@{{ item.name }}</span>
</div>

<div>
  <autocomplete-component></autocomplete-component>
</div>
```

autocomplete-component.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    item: {required:true},
    searchText: {required:true}
  },
  data () {
        return {
            item: {id: 9, name: 'Lion', description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.'},
            items: [],
        }
  },
  methods: {
    getLabel (item) {
      return item.name
    },

  }
};
</script>
```

How can I make it so that the autocomplete div can exist in the blade but use the function and data in the included component?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to use [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots-with-the-slot-scope-Attribute).

In your `autocomplete.vue` you would need to insert a slot and the provide the slot with the item.

Roughly speaking -

Autocomplete:

```
<template>
    <slot :item="item"></slot>
</template>

// ...script etc
```

Blade view:

```
<autocomplete :items="items" v-model="item" :get-label="getLabel" :component-item='template' @update-items="updateItems">
    <template v-slot:default="slotProps">
        @{{ slotProps.item }}
    </template>

    // OR
    <template v-slot:default="{item}">
        @{{ item }}
    </template>
</autocomplete>
```